# Solving ${{2x - 3}\choose{1- x^2}} = 3$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was given this problem by my sister, she took it from a past paper in her calculus class (12 grade).

As the title reads, we are asked to solve the equation:

> $${{2x - 3}\choose{1- x^2}} = 3$$

Now this seems a particularly strange problem to me. I see no way to solve this, provided that they haven't studied anything regarding binomial expansions with rational coefficients.

After going through the base conditions that $x$ should satisfy and trying some combinatorial identities I came empty handed. Wolfram Alpha provides a numerical solution that I don't see how to come by using pen and paper.

How would you solve this without making any use of any mathematical apparatus (i.e. gamma function) behind high school level calculus?

Comment: Maybe she is supposed to solve it in terms of non-negative integral entries, it that case there are no solutions.

Comment: Probably a typo.....Not again :( It is impossible to solve through highchool mathematics (I am saying this with confidence because I am also a 12th Grade student)

Comment: I'm of the same opinion...

Comment: The entries must be non-negative, so $x>1$ from the top entry, and $x<1$ from the bottom entry:  Hence no solution.  There *must* be a typo.  A sign change would admit $x=0$.

Comment: As said by Mr. David, I strongly agree that it should be `2x+3` rather than `2x-3`. This will lead a solution $x=0$.

Comment: How do you even define binomial coefficient for the case when $n>k\geq 0$ is not true?Most likely your sister doesn't have any definition apart from when $n>k\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If the binomial coefficient ${{n}\choose{k}}$ is defined only for $n>k\ge 0$ and integers, than $n=2x-3$ and $k=1-x^2$ is not possible because the system
$$
\begin{cases}
1-x^2\ge 0\\
2x-3>1-x^2
\end{cases}
$$
has no solutions in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Everybody here knows that.You must read OP properly - `I see no way to solve this,**provided** that they haven't studied anything regarding binomial expansions with rational coefficients.`

Comment: @JaideepKhare:  I apologize, but maybe that I've some problem in translation.  The OP statement does not means that the students does known only the binomial coefficient with positive integer entries? If so, my answer say that this kind of coefficient is impossible in this case.